# Discovery management pages (connections, scanners..) - displays in disable mode

Tags: discovery

in master - I can't navigate to discovery management pages (connections, scanners..) - they all displays in disable mode

Answer (score 0):

in subscriptions table - filter to your account_id, order the rows by created_at, and set the 'plan_code' column of the latest row with 'ultimate' value.